# Deletion from DB Set fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two tables written in EF CodeFirst:

```
public class DayType
{
    [Key]
    public int DayTypeID { get; set; }
    public string NameDayType { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<SpecialDay> Specialdays { get; set; }
    public DayType() { }
}

public class SpecialDay
{
    [Key]
    public int SpecialDayID { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int JanuaryDay { get; set; }
    public SpecialDay() { }
    public int? DayTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual DayType daytype { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext relation one-to-many were made by FluentAPI:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SpecialDay>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.daytype)
            .WithMany(p => p.Specialdays);
```

There I have form for CRUD operation with  `DayType` were, when user presses delete button it calls object `RelayCommand` and then SelectedDayType(Binding -correct, `INotifyPropertyChanged` - implemented) goes to the next function for deleting:

```
internal void Delete(DayType dt)
{          
    using (SalDBContext _dbContext = new SalDBContext())
    {
        try
        {
            DayType daytype = _dbContext.DayTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DayTypeID == dt.DayTypeID);

            _dbContext.Entry(dt).Collection(c=>c.Specialdays).Load();
            _dbContext.DayTypes.Remove(dt);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
    }
}
```

Moreover, during debugging I have errors. I would be very thankful for help. My mistakes and points were they appears during debug my delete function:

1. `using (SalDBContext _dbContext = new SalDBContext()) {`

at this point I  have object `dt` with correct properties `DayTypeID` and `NameDayType`. However property `Specialdays` throw Exception type

> System.ObjectDisposedException     System.Collections.Generic.ICollection {System.ObjectDisposedException}

2. Then I take next steps. At line:

   `DayType daytype = _dbContext.DayTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DayTypeID == dt.DayTypeID);`

daytype has corectly display all properties. but after

```
`_dbContext.Entry(dt).Collection(c=>c.Specialdays).Load();`
```

it catches exception

> Member 'Load' cannot be called for property 'Specialdays' because the entity of type 'DayType' does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet. System.InvalidOperationException

3) When I tried run only:

```
  _dbContext.DayTypes.Remove(dt);
  _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It throws next exception

> "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager." System.InvalidOperationException

Would be thankful for any help with solution for my problems. Thank you

Comment: The tracked item you are fetching is `daytype`, but your code tries to remove the item `dt` which is not in the context as the error states. Try `_dbContext.DayTypes.Remove(daytype);`

Comment: I don't know where `dt` comes from but it obviously a problem. Try this `_dbContext.Entry(daytype).Collection...`

Comment: @SteveGreene Thank you but it doesn't help.Poiner stopped after `_dbContext.Entry(dt).Collection(c=>c.Specialdays).Load();` and then it goes to  ` catch(exception ex)`

Comment: @T.S. i have ListBox where all items in our table is displayed and when we selected item pass to function comes 1 point. Adding and Updating Value works  good.

Comment: see, you have error that says `Object Disposed`. So, your collection, which is probably a `HashSet` has been disposed. May be you used `using` somewhere to iterate `daytype.Specialdays`? **Your code doesn't show source of an issue**

Comment: Thank you @T.S. Problem was solved. The next code is correct    

             DayType daytype = _db.DayTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DayTypeID == dt.DayTypeID);
             _db.Entry(daytype).Collection(c => c.Specialdays).Load();
             _db.DayTypes.Remove(daytype);

Comment: At least couple of us told you to do that